# samba+openldap vs ad for medium size network

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, samba, openldap

We are going to have an organized network with an NT user authentication and proxy server. In choosing between Active Directory and Samba Server, I wanted to choose Samba server (I do love Open Source ). Our plan has a Forest (root : [domainname]) and trees for sub-domains (like: eng.[domainname], maybe with some children) and maybe for internet site (Sites where users just use Internet) we may have a new forest (we should have trust between these domains). In every site we should have DC and Squid Proxy server (for control and traffic shaping the internet in the with high performance) . 
All of our clients are using Win XP or Seven.
And we are also going to use MOSS 2007.

The problem are: 
- Can we completely handle our plan with Samba server? ,with replication and trusts? ,what should we do? Should we use OpenLDAP for our plan? What do you suggest for ? Which distribution of Linux do you recommend for our plan? Won't we have problem using these with MOSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I believe in OpenSource. What I believe in even more is using the right tool for the job. From what you have provided trying to use openLDAP + SAMBA will be like trying to shove a round peg into a sqaure hole. Especially at the size your deployment sounds like. If your clients are all running Windows, then Use active directory.

Group Policy alone is enough in my opinion to make this a no brainer.

Now with that said, that doesn't mean you have to run Windows on all of your servers. Once again using the right tool for the job comes into play. Run your SQUID proxy servers on Linux and authenticate them against active directory.

You should probably use CentOS (or redhat if your university wants a support contract) Debian, or Ubuntu LTS.

To directly answer a few of your questions that I havn't answered above:

Can you do everthing with samba? Probably but honestly I think it would be more trouble than it's worth, and you won't get the full benefits of AD

You need Windows (and i think in the new version AD) to use sharepoint

You might be able to get away with using mono the run .net applications - but once again it would probably be more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: tnx , can you answer this question too ?
http://serverfault.com/questions/97347/active-directory-squid-planning-for-a-large-network-with-over-than-7000-users

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Samba's AD support is coming in Samba 4, which is not ready to be deployed by regular users yet.

Ubuntu LTS is my personal suggestion.

Comment: tnx , can you answer this question too ?
http://serverfault.com/questions/97347/active-directory-squid-planning-for-a-large-network-with-over-than-7000-users